# What site variables can I use GitHub pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to build the best GitHub pages page I can and would love to be able to offer more helpful links to the repository than just "Improve this Page".

I'm using the default Jekyll theme and would like to understand:

1. How does "Improve This Page" show up?
2. What other information about my repo/project is there?

Any helpful resources are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figuring this out was really illuminating!

It took some digging in my GitHub Jobs.

When "Pages Deploy and Publish" runs, I see something like this
[image: GitHub Action Output]

The theme GitHub Pages is using, if I don't specify one, is [Primer](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer)

Primer's default layout is where we get the "Improve this Page" link.  Specifically, Improve this Page is *referenced* in [_layouts/default.html, on line 22](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/blob/master/_layouts/default.html#L22).

Notice I said *referenced*.  Primer doesn't define `github_edit_link` (the Liquid tag used to make the link).

That led me a bit further down the rabbit hole to find the dependency:

[image: Another Clue]

Once that veil had been pierced, I took a look at [jekyll-github-metadata](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/)

This is where I found the treasure trove of information I had been looking for!

[This Markdown Document Lists All Of The Site-Wide Variables](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/blob/main/docs/site.github.md)

I've added some descriptions to each:

| Site Variable | Description |
| --- | --- |
| hostname | Always `github.com` |
| pages_hostname | Always `github.io` |
| api_url | Always `https://api.github.com` |
| help_url | `https://help.github.com` |
| environment | Always `dotcom` |
| pages_env | Always `dotcom` |
| public_repositories | The Publisher's public repositories |
| organization_members | The members of the Publisher's Organization |
| build_revision | The build revision (the commithash) |
| project_title | The Name of the Repository |
| project_tagline | The repository description |
| owner_name | The Owner of the repository |
| owner_url | The Owner's public GitHub URL |
| owner_gravatar_url | The Owner's GitHub Avatar! |
| repository_url | The full URL for the repository |
| repository_nwo | The root-relative URL of the repository |
| repository_name | The name of the repository |
| zip_url | A URL to the zipped contents of the repository |
| tar_url | A URL to the tarball contents of the repository |
| clone_url | The URL to the git repo |
| releases_url | The URL for the Repository's releases |
| issues_url | The URL for the Repository's issues |
| wiki_url | The URL for the Repository's wikis |
| language | Unsure, but I'd guess it's the language ;-) |
| is_user_page | Unsure, but I'd guess this indicates if this is a page for a user |
| is_project_page | Unsure, but I'd guess this indicates if this was a project |
| show_downloads | If downloads should be displayed |
| url | The public URL or CNAME |
| baseurl | The root-relative base URL (most likely `/`) |
| contributors | Contributors to the Project |
| releases | Releases of the project |
| latest_release | The latest GitHub Release Object |
| private | If the repository is private or not |
| archived | If the repository has been archived |
| disabled | If the repository was disabled |

Hopefully this content saves the next person the time and effort to track this down.